# animation to show from a PNG sequence Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, png, ccsprite

i want to make animation to show from a PNG sequence but this code only show me the first image of the sequence, please help me to modify this code to work

This is the Code:

```
CCSprite *character= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1-enable001.png"]];

character.position = ccp(240*g_fx, 151*g_fy);
[characterList addObject:character];
[self addChild:character ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CCSprite *character = [[CCSprite alloc] init];//Create sprite

anim = [[CCAnimation animation] retain];//Create animation
[anim addFrameWithFilename:@"1-enable001.png"];//Animation1.png
[anim addFrameWithFilename:@"1-enable002.png"];//Animation2.png
[anim addFrameWithFilename:@"1-enable003.png"];//Animation3.png
id animateAction = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:2.0f animation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];

[sprite runAction:animateAction];//Run animation
```